# Manipulators, C++ what order should I use them in?

Tags: c++, manipulators

I am trying to learn about manipulators...is there a specific order for them?

For ex does `std::setw` come after or before `std::setfill` and should they be in separate lines?

Comment: Well-formatted example / sscce please.

Answer (score 2):

There's no specific order, just make sure you include the `<iomanip>` library.

Example on your setw/setfil question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout  << setw(10) << setfill('*');
    cout << 123;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not specific order. But please note this, for example, if you want to use std::left and std::right, or write everything in one line then things can get bit tricky.

For example this will not print expected output (prints just: `7`
):

`std::cout << std::setw(10) << std::left << 7 << std::setfill('x') << std::endl;`

Because you need to **set attributes first**, then print whatever you want. So all three lines below will work, no matter their places change (prints: `xxxxxxxxx7`):

```
std::cout << std::setw(10) << std::setfill('x') << std::right << 7 << std::endl;
std::cout << std::right << std::setw(10) << std::setfill('x') << 7 << std::endl;
std::cout << std::setfill('x') << std::right << std::setw(10) << 7 << std::endl;
```

And the code below is just to clarify things.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::setw(15) << std::setfill('-') << "PRODUCT" << std::setw(15) << std::setfill('-') << "AMOUNT" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setw(15) << std::setfill('-') << "Brush"  << std::setw(15) << std::setfill('-') << 10 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setw(15) << std::setfill('-') << "Paste"  << std::setw(15) << std::setfill('-') << 8 << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::setw(15) << std::left << std::setfill('-') << "PRODUCT" << std::setw(15) << std::left << std::setfill('-') << "AMOUNT" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setw(15) << std::left << std::setfill('-') << "Brush"  << std::setw(15) << std::left << std::setfill('-') << 10 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setw(15) << std::left << std::setfill('-') << "Paste"  << std::setw(15) << std::left << std::setfill('-') << 8 << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::setw(15) << std::right << std::setfill('-') << "PRODUCT" << std::setw(15) << std::right << std::setfill('-') << "AMOUNT" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setw(15) << std::right << std::setfill('-') << "Brush"  << std::setw(15) << std::right << std::setfill('-') << 10 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setw(15) << std::right << std::setfill('-') << "Paste"  << std::setw(15) << std::right << std::setfill('-') << 8 << std::endl << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```